# FacebookBundle installation error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

can someone know how to solve this error :

```
                   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- The requested package friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle could not be found in any 
  version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-
   stability setting
  see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more 
  details.

  Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common 
  problems.
```

I have this error when I try to install FacebookBunle in Symfony 2.1.6 :

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also your solution Marcos García does not work ! I used Symfony 2.1.6 so I had the same problem.

The solution is to download your Symfony version without vendor and you update your composer.json after you do :

```
php composer.phar update 

or

php composer phar install
```

Now all will work very  fine just don't forget to install Curl and Git too.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is your minimum-stability setting? As you can see in [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle) there's no stable version available (yet), so you have either to:

- Modify your composer.json file and add `@dev` at the end of the version number. For example:

  ```
  "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "*@dev",
  ```
- Modify your minimum-stability setting from `stable` to `dev`